# How to tell Apple if there are spelling mistakes in its application document?

Tags: ipad

For example I just installed some Apple software on my iPad. Before I start using it I need to agree its terms & conditions.

While I was reading the terms & conditions there are spelling mistakes I found in the document.

How should I report this to Apple?

Comment: https://bugreport.apple.com - but I'd make sure they're not just US/UK English differences etc.

Comment: Curious to know what was the spelling mistake!

Answer (score 2):

[Apple Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/) is the essential site to report these issues.

You'll need to have a developer account though which you could always setup for free and that should gain you access to the Bug Reporting tool.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a lot of [contact details](http://www.apple.com/contact/) on their website. At the bottom of it, there is a link to a [list of feedback forms](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) for various products and applications.